# Logger interceptor is not calling in spring boot security project

Tags: spring-boot, logging, interceptor

I have used Spring boot 4 version project with spring security. I have tried to implement logger interceptor in my project and that is not working.

> Logger Interceptor Class

```html
@Component
public class LoggerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest requestServlet, HttpServletResponse responseServlet, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("MINIMAL: INTERCEPTOR PREHANDLE CALLED");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("MINIMAL: INTERCEPTOR POSTHANDLE CALLED");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception
    {   
        System.out.println("MINIMAL: INTERCEPTOR AFTERCOMPLETION CALLED");
    }
}
```

> Config class

```html
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    LoggerInterceptor logInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

}
```

I have tried the above code in simple spring boot project it is working fine, but while tried on my project it is not calling the interceptor.

Please throw some light for this.

Comment: did you add @Configuration annotation to your InterceptorConfig  class ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to insert on the above code.

Comment: did it worked ?

Comment: Actually I made a silly mistake here. I wrongly created the package. So that it is not called